# Converting coordinates into map addresses

Tags: php, gps

I am developing a GPS Server and tracking system:

1. How can I convert latitudes and longitudes data got from a GPS tracking device into address data so that the client application report be displaying road names instead of coordinates?
2. How can I map the coordinate data so that tracker position be displayed on a map i.e. google maps or vector maps?

I'll highly appreciate your answers or suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use a reverse geocoder. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding
2. Use a mapping API like Google Maps. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/

Comment: Thanks. I'll go through your suggested web links.

Comment: Reverse geocoder works as per your answer. However some tracking devices send coordinate information in different format e.g. 0116.8635S, 03645.5796E which becomes a bit tough to plot on the following geocoder
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q="latitude","longtitude"&output=csv&sensor=false

Any suggestions on how to plot the above coordinates will be appreciated.

Comment: You'd need to convert them from whatever format that is to standard notation.

Comment: Thanks ceejayoz I got the solution as per your guidance. the lat and long from the device are in Decimal Degree minutes format while the geocoder link required Decimal Degrees format.

Answer (score 0):

Here you find [How to convert GPS coordinates to a full address with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395367/how-to-convert-gps-coordinates-to-a-full-address-with-php)

And in Ruby:

```
require 'curb'

require 'json'

class GpsUtils

GOOGLE_MAP_URL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="

class << self

  # Return the address
  def convert_from_gps_coordinates_to_address(lat, long)
    response = Curl.get(GOOGLE_MAP_URL + lat + "," + long)
    json_response = JSON.parse(response.body_str)
    # Read the full address (formatted_address) from json_response
    json_response["results"].first["formatted_address"] 
  end 

end 

end

GpsUtils.convert_from_gps_coordinates_to_address("19.43250", "-99.1330"
```

Comment: @JuanRicardo: The solution in Ruby was suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4939541) by you *Juan Ricardo*