# How to convert GPS coordinates to a full address with php?

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, gps

I have GPS coordinates in the form `54.1456123 10.413456`.

How can I convert them with PHP to addresses with postal code, street and city?

Comment: Try google maps API  [Refer this post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441521/get-address-from-google-map-api-v3-in-english

Comment: This is not a duplicate: here I ask how to achieve this with PHP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use google API

```
$lat="54.1456123";
$long = "10.413456";

$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$lat,$long&sensor=false";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
$curlData = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$address = json_decode($curlData);
print_r($address);
```

Comment: you might need to signup with Google API --   and get keyws etc. from them.

Comment: I tried it without Google API key and without curl: `$curlData=file_get_contents( $url);` that worked, thanks

Comment: only for limited queries

Answer (score 6):

Without `curl` nor API-key needed:

```
function geo2address($lat,$long) {
    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$lat,$long&sensor=false";
    $curlData=file_get_contents(    $url);
    $address = json_decode($curlData);
    $a=$address->results[0];
    return explode(",",$a->formatted_address);
}
```