# Converting GPS coordinates captured to address in PHP

Tags: php, android, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I want to change real-time coordinates captured from my google maps to address.

I've tried the following code:

```
<?php

$lat="9.102097";
$long="-40.187988";
geo2address($lat,$long);

function geo2address($lat,$long) {

$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$lat,$long&sensor=false";
$curlData=file_get_contents(    $url);
$address = json_decode($curlData);
$a=$address->results[0];
return explode(",",$a->formatted_address);
print_r($address);
}

?>
```

P.S. I'm testing with a fixed coordinates but will capture coordinates from my application when I success

I referenced the code from [How to convert GPS coordinates to a full address with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395367/how-to-convert-gps-coordinates-to-a-full-address-with-php/16397083#16397083) but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with the `$url` itself, such as:

- You're using `http` in the URL, whereas you should use `https`.
- You're not using `key` parameter in the URL. Sign up for an API KEY and use it in the URL.

Here's an example of one such URL:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY`
```

Here's the documentation of reverse geocoding:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding

So your code should be like this:

```
$lat="40.714224";
$long="-73.961452";
geo2address($lat,$long);

function geo2address($lat,$long) {
    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$lat,$long&key=YOUR_API_KEY";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    $a = $json['results'][0]['formatted_address'];
    print_r(explode(",",$a));
}
```

Few points to note here is:

- The latitude and longitude are taken from the documentation itself.
- Pass the second parameter as `true` in the `json_decode()` function to convert it into associative array. It will be then easy for you to access individual components.

Comment: @Xinee Yes, you can do that. Just pass the dynamic latitude and longitude arguments to `geo2address()` function whenever you call this function.

Comment: @Xinee Glad I could help. Please *accept* the answer if it resolved your issue. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)